# mod_rewrite later rule overide general rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file that contains the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ departmentpage.php?dep=$1&pagename=$2
```

I want to create a contact page and want the later specific rule override the previous, like cascading stylesheets.

The following rule looks like its getting ignored:

```
RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)/contact$ departmentpage.php?dep=$1&
```

Is there anyway for the 2nd more specific rewrite to override the general rewrite?

```
RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ departmentpage.php?dep=$1&pagename=$2
RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)/contact$ departmentpage.php?dep=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the rules (and use [L] if necessary).